# Загрузить картинки по FTP на сервер по средствам библиотеки requests в Python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!

Есть ли возможность Загрузить несколько картинок по FTP на сервер по средствам библиотеки requests в Python?

У меня есть массив с ссылками на картинки которые надо закинуть на сервер.. Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: `ftplib` примеры здесь можно глянуть и в других ответах https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613970/8324991

Comment: Меня интересует именно библиотека requests... так сервис где я буду это применять работает только с этой библиотекой.. а ссылке в которой вы мне посоветовали там обсуждается библиотека ftplib...

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно, поскольку библиотека `requests` работает только с `http(s)` протоколом.

Comment: Может я не правильно сформировал вопрос.... имеется виду FTP.. у меня есть массив с ссылками на картинки мне нужно залить эти картинки на свой файловый сервер.. Это возможно по средствами библиотеки requests?

Comment: @FaridFarkhadov невозможно. потому что `https` и `ftp` - разные протоколы. `requests` работает только с `https`

Comment: Я имею ввиду.. возможно ли по средствам  https загрузить  картинки на свой файловый сервер?

Comment: requests
logger
gspread
oauth2client
numpy
pyzbar
fuzzywuzzy
python-Levenshtein
re
urllib
time
telethon
json
hmac
hashlib
beautifulsoup4
pandas
base64
xmltodict
mysql-connector-python
zeep
google-api-python-client

Comment: Я могу использовать только эти библиотеки

Comment: @FaridFarkhadov urllib, насколько я знаю может работать с FTP, но это уже другой вопрос